Video player with dynamic pointer to prevent recording
I would like to implement a video player in my web platform. Where the admin would upload videos and then the users could watch them. And I came to an idea to implement some sort of protection against screen recording.
How hard would it be to implement a small pointer showing the users email for example (Something like in Figma when you have an another user on the same page as you). This small pointer would randomly fly/roam around the video making it not static on the video.
I would retrieve the videos from youtube so is there a player that already has this functionality, and if there isn't what player would be best to personalize and implement this functionality in?
